# Connecting Sheets to BigQuery

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to connect a Google Sheets to a new BigQuery table that populates and updates the data automatically from Sheets to BigQuery. I'm using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bigquery-integrates-with-google-drive) from Google itself to do the setup.

**My problem: the table connected with spreadsheet was created empty so I had to query it and save the result as another table to see and use the data.**

I can't post images yet so I ask you please to check this [imgur post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmJwe.jpg), please.

I'm not expert in these things but does not seems to be the best way to do it. I found some spreadsheet add-ons but I'm trying to avoid them.

Any ideas what's the best way to do this kind of setup/connection?

Comment: Looking at the image you added not sure why you think the source table is empty, Is this because in the UI you see `table size: 0`. This is the default display of external table. The fact that you managed to query the table and saved the results to another table is proof the table is not actually empty. Hope this clarifies the issue for you

Answer (score 2):

> I had to configure each column manually

BigQuery provides a variety of tools which make it pretty simple to connect the external table to BigQuery.

One option is to simply use the WebUi and the *Auto Detect* option which help you **not to enter** each column manually

[image]

This works perfectly for me also when inserting and adding data to the external table.

You can refer to BigQuery official manual on an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) for more help

Comment: Thank you for the explanation in this point. I mentioned the manual config because I didn't know if this would impact in the second, and most important, problem: the table went empty so I have to query it to another table to bring the data.I would post a image but I don't know how to do it here when not creating a new question.

Comment: You can edit your question and add any relevant data using this link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55794303/edit. But table doesn't go empty without a reason so I feel you need to provide more background before we can get tor the bottom of this. Please explain how you query the table and it was empty but manage to query the table to another table.

Comment: @IgorSouza Are you looking to bring data from sheets into BQ or from BQ into sheets?

Comment: @TamirKlein I updated the post with some useful info.

Comment: @WvonR from sheets to BQ. I included this info in the original post.